# How to create delete button on mousehover like gmail in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, ag-grid-react

I want to display the delete action button on the mouse hover of each row like Gmail in AgGrid react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using custom [`cellRenderer`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#react-cell-rendering) in react, as ag-grid doesn't provide a way to do that out of box.

You can use css styling to show the buttons only on hover of row. ag-grid applies `ag-row-hover` class to the hovered row so you make use of this class.